# Simple lemma in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I've been trying to learn how to use Isabelle and I've come across a problem. The following lemma works:

```
lemma sum_square: "(a+b)^2=a^2+(2::real)*a*b+b^2"
apply (simp add: power2_eq_square) 
output: (a + b) * (a + b) = a * a + 2 * a * b + b * b
```

however the following lemma does not:

```
lemma sum_sq: "(a+b)^2 = (a+b) * (a+b)"
apply (simp add: power2_eq_square)
output: Failed to apply proof method
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also, can anyone direct me to Isabelle tutorials or simple proofs I can work through to increase my knowledge of Isabelle?

Comment: Does specifying types for a, b work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Isabelle several operators like multiplication, addition, exponentiation, etc. are polymorphic and purely syntactical. I.e., in your statement `(a+b)^2 = (a+b) * (a+b)` the type of `a` and `b` can be anything, and is not necessarily a number type.

You can detect such cases by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-hover on the corresponding lemma and variables. E.g., `power2_eq_square` is defined within the context `monoid_mult`, i.e., only if `a` and `b` are of a type which also is a `monoid_mult`, then the lemma applies. However, the type of `a` is `'a :: {numeral,power}`.

Concerning tutorials, just click on `Documentation` on the right-hand side of the Isabelle/jEdit window,
and then the two tutorials `prog-prove` and `tutorial` become visible.